# How can I get list of pairs words with their length in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list:

```
items = ["beef", "pork", "ham"]
```

and I need to return a list with word + length of each word

```
[("beef", 4), ("pork", 4), ("ham", 3)]
```

Comment: Seems like a homework... At least show us some code you have tried and where you are stuck !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that as:

```
a = [(i, len(i)) for i in items]
```

#### Example

```
items = ["beef", "pork", "ham"]
a = [(i, len(i)) for i in items]

>>> print a
[("beef", 4), ("pork", 4), ("ham", 3)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use list comprehension, like this

```
[(item, len(item)) for item in items]
# [('beef', 4), ('pork', 4), ('ham', 3)]
```